# MySQL/PHP Refining join query for searching multiple tables

Tags: php, sql

I need to perform a search across 18 separate SQL tables for a string. The search will be looking in differently named fields and multiple fields on some tables.

While I can achieve this with something like the below (the first 2 tables), I feel the code is going to get very unwieldy once all 18 tables are joined.

Is there any way I can refine this code?

Also when the result is given can I find out with PHP which table the answer came from?

```
mysql_query("SELECT a.about,b.title,b.article,b.description

FROM about a 
JOIN articles b ON b.user=a.user

WHERE (upper(a.about)  LIKE'%".$val."%')  OR  (upper(b.title)  LIKE'%".$val."%') OR  (upper(b.article)  LIKE'%".$val."%') OR  (upper(b.descirption)  LIKE'%".$val."%')  ORDER BY $order $max");
```

Comment: Smells of SQL Injection...

Comment: Which kind of content is this? Why is it in 18 different tables? Feels like it's a database design problem, first of all.

Comment: I agree with @Qualcuno, sounds like a database design flaw.  As to, "find[ing] out with PHP which table the answer came from", you could always label your selected columns with a prefix:  "a.about as a_about".

Comment: The tables have to be separate, that's just the way it is.

Comment: If you are concerned with performance of the query, I think applying a function like `UPPER` on columns in `WHERE` condition would not allow the Database to use index, so it would be better if you could accommodate these functions in the PHP code.

Comment: @user1209203 It could still help to understand why they need to be separate, and what is your database structure.

Comment: That would be a really long and involved answer, but basically this is for a "site search" so there is good reason why the tables are separate.

Comment: @user1209203 If you want to do a site-wide search, you may then want to do it right. First, don't use "LIKE", but a proper full-text search (uses indexes, has more features). You may also consider having a table named "contents" where you put all the texts from all tables (and then just use joins to match rows). You may even consider using Redis or Sphinx for doing a good job.

Comment: What is a "proper full-text search" how would I get more information on that?

Comment: @user1209203 Google "mysql full text". A starter could be: http://blog.marceloaltmann.com/en-using-the-mysql-fulltext-index-search-pt-utilizando-mysql-fulltext/ If you use "LIKE" MySQL can't use indexes and so the search can be PAINFULLY slow (as the db needs to go through all rows every time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION

```
SELECT about from some WHERE about like '%some%'
UNION 
SELECT about from some_other WHERE about like '%some%'
```

and if you want to allow duplicate results use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the `UNION` operation.

```
select x from table_1 where blabla
union
select y from table_2 where blabla
```

and so on.

`x` and `y` must be the same format.

Comment: @lovor I am selecting different fields from each table though